# Styling the :visited pseudo element

Tags: css

Which styles can I apply to a :visited link?
It seems only color is working.

I understand the privacy issue. Is there a non invasive way of styling :visited links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited) and [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) have this to say:

> *Note: It is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the :link and :visited pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the user's consent.*
>
> UAs may therefore treat all links as unvisited links, or implement other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited and unvisited links differently.

So, according the standards, you can't really depend on styling `a:visited` at all. My experience is that all the browsers will pay attention to the coloring properties (as noted by Soufiane Hassou for Gecko browsers) but little else.

Comment: I understand how I can use JS to determine visibility of a link and therefore if  the user visited.... but I can still do the same thing from detecting color. I don't get how removing half the rules solves anything. *sigh*

Comment: @Dave: You could play tricks with `background-image: url(...)` in straight CSS. I could probably think up a few other tricks using `url()` if I was so inclined.

Answer (score 6):

> You will still be able to visually
>   style visited links, but there are now
>   limits on what styles you can use.
>   Only the following properties can be
>   applied to visited links:
>
> - color
> - background-color
> - border-color (and its sub-properties)
> - outline-color
> - The color parts of the fill and stroke properties

[MDC - Privacy and the :visited selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector#Limits_to_visited_link_styles)